# How to find the Request is Soap request or Rest Request

Tags: spring-boot, rest, soap

We have requirement to expose Soap endpoint and Rest endpoint in single spring boot application.
we have same business logic for both of the request.
But while preparing the response we have to change the date format differently for soap and rest responses.

Is there any spring property which can be used to identify the incoming request is soap or rest, based on that,  we can have if else condition to change the date format.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring, but SOAP messages are XML whereas REST is JSON. But other than that, you would typically have separate endpoints for each protocol. They can be in the same host.